# Guice field injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

So here's the thing. I'm trying to inject some fields with guice, but it turns out that they are always null (not trying to use them on the constructor).

```
public class A {

    @Inject
    private SomeClass bar;

    public A() {
        foo();
    }

    public someMethod() {
        bar.doSth();
    }

}

public class B {

    private A a;

    public B() {
        a = new A();
    }

    public someOtherMethod() {
        a.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Now whenever the app executed someOtherMethod and a tries to run bar.doSth a nice NullPointerException is raised.

So in order to fix this i ended Injecting the field manually inside the constructor:

```
public A() {
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
    bar = injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class);
}
```

But this is ugly, unclear, has a lot of boilerplate and I'm forced to do it on many places which make it tedious.

Is there any other way to archive this? Or an explanation of why the field is not being injected?

Thanks

Note:
    I'm currently unavailable to do the propper injection on the constructor (with bar as a parameter) because of the refactoring it would imply. The project is now under heavy production and thus this kind of refactoring can't be done right now.

Comment: injection is not "deus ex machina". For object created with classic 'new' doesnt occur  (few additions or pathes is possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IOC container only controls what you tell it to control. It doesn't know about the `A` inside of `B`, because it's being constructed directly, not managed by the container. You need to `inject` the `A` as well:

```
public class B {
    @inject private A a;

    public B() {}

    ...
}
```

And you can't just call `new B()` either, you need to inject the `B` as well.

Comment: So guice is basicaly viral? I must inject everything in order for it to work?

Comment: Most DI systems are "viral" in that way

Comment: I prefer to think of it as forcing the Inversion of Control through the whole stack. There are other approaches like injecting a provider, or as you discovered manually asking the container: `injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class)`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. They were very helpful.